# why Macs on the networks failing to access but windows is able to?

Tags: google-chrome, dns, domain

We have multiple machines on the same network with 2 Apple Macs, why Macs are unable to access `https://pub.dartlang.org/` but windows does it?
I am getting `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` on my Mac

NOTE: `https://pub.dartlang.org/` points to `pub.dev` and I am using chrome, everything was alright till yesterday